# Is there any way to speed up this loop?

Tags: r

I am pretty new to programming and am looking for help to speed up this process. At the current rate the loop will take approximately 24-30 hours.

```
library(readxl)

## Load data##
A02_pre <- read_excel("C:/Users/Gebruiker/Desktop/Nieuwe map/Mappen participanten/Pre/A02/A02_vivo13_wk2_4mei_90uur.xlsx", 
                                         col_types = c("text", "text", "text", 
                                                       "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
                                                       "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
                                                       "text", "text", "text", "numeric", 
                                                       "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
                                                       "numeric", "numeric", "text", "numeric", 
                                                       "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
                                                       "numeric", "numeric", "text", "numeric", 
                                                       "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
                                                       "text", "text"))




A02_pre_hr <- read_excel("C:/Users/Gebruiker/Desktop/Nieuwe map/Mappen participanten/Pre/A02/A02 - 17817.xlsx", )
View(A02_pre_hr)


### Convert string to date time ##
A02_pre$`ns1:Time` = as.POSIXct(A02_pre$`ns1:Time`, 
                                                   format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OSZ",tz ="GMT")
A02_pre_hr$start = as.POSIXct(substr(A02_pre_hr$start,1,nchar(A02_pre_hr$start)-4), 
                                     format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz ="GMT")

## Test dates ##
A02_pre$`ns1:Time`[1] < A02_pre_hr$start[1]



measurementTime <- A02_pre$`ns1:Time`
heartRate <- A02_pre$`ns1:Value4`



**### Run for loop starting here 
toCheck = 1:length(measurementTime)
maxj = 0
for(i in 1:(nrow(A02_pre_hr)-1)){
  
  activityStartTime = A02_pre_hr$start[i]
  
  activityEndTime= A02_pre_hr$start[i+1]
  
  heartRateSum = 0
  heartRateCount = 0
  
  ## Loop over heart rate measurements & assign average to activity
  for(j in toCheck[toCheck>maxj]){
    
    
    if(measurementTime[j]>=activityStartTime & measurementTime[j]<= activityEndTime){
      
      heartRateCount = heartRateCount+1
      heartRateSum = heartRateSum + heartRate[j]

    }else if(heartRateCount>0){
      break;
    }
  }
  averageHeartRate = NA
  if(heartRateCount>0){
    averageHeartRate = heartRateSum / heartRateCount
  }
  A02_pre_hr$averageHeartRate[i] = averageHeartRate
  print(i)
}**


### Summary ####
by(A02_pre_hr$averageHeartRate, A02_pre_hr$class, summary)
```

```
dput(A02_pre)
structure(list(`ns1:Value4` = c(78, 77, 82, 87, 92, 97, 99, 100, 
101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 105, 104, 103, 102, 101, 100, 99, 
98, 97, 96, 97, 98, 99, 101, 102, 104, 105, 106, 105, 104, 103, 
102, 101, 100, 99, 98, 97, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 99, 100, 
101, 100, 99, 98, 97, 96, 95, 94, 93, 92, 91, 90, 89, 94, 98, 
100, 101, 99, 97, 96, 95, 94, 93, 94, 93, 92, 91, 90, 89, 90, 
89, 88, 85, 83, 82, 81, 80, 79, 78, 77, 75, 74, 72, 71, 70, 69, 
68, 67, 66, 65, 64, 63, 62, 63, 62, 65, 68, 71, 73, 75, 77, 79, 
81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 90, 89, 88, 87, 86, 
85, 84, 83, 82, 81, 80, 79, 78, 77, 76, 75, 74, 75, 74, 73, 72, 
71, 70, 69, 68, 67, 66, 65, 67, 68, 69, 68, 67, 71, 74, 77, 79, 
81, 83, 85, 87, 88, 90, 89, 88, 89, 88, 87, 86, 85, 84, 83, 85, 
87, 89, 90, 92, 91, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 
101, 102, 103, 107, 111, 114, 117, 117, 116, 115, 116, 117, 118, 
119, 120, 119, 117, 116, 115, 114, 113, 112, 111, 110, 109, 108, 
107, 106, 105, 104, 103, 102, 100, 99, 98, 97, 96, 95, 94, 93, 
92, 90, 88, 89, 90, 91, 93, 94, 95, 96, 95, 94, 93, 92, 91, 90, 
89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 98, 97, 96, 97, 98, 
99, 100, 99, 98, 97, 98, 97, 96, 95, 94, 93, 92, 91, 90, 91, 
90, 89, 87, 85, 83, 81, 80, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 
88, 89, 90, 95, 98, 102, 105, 107, 110, 112, 114, 116, 115, 114, 
113, 112, 111, 110, 109, 108, 107, 106, 105, 104, 103, 102, 101, 
100, 99, 98, 97, 96, 95, 94, 95, 94, 95, 96, 95, 94, 93, 94, 
93, 92, 91, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 99, 100, 103, 105, 
106, 108, 107, 106, 105, 104, 105, 106, 105, 104, 105, 106, 107, 
106, 105, 104, 103, 104, 103, 104, 100, 99, 98, 97, 96, 95, 94, 
93, 92, 93, 94, 95, 97, 98, 99, 100, 99, 100, 101, 100, 99, 100, 
99, 98, 99, 100, 99, 100, 99, 97, 94, 91, 89, 90, 89, 88, 87, 
85, 84, 85, 86, 87, 86, 85, 83, 81, 80, 79, 78, 77, 76, 75, 74, 
72, 71, 70, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 80, 81, 83, 
84, 85, 86, 85, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 91, 
89, 88, 87, 88, 89, 90, 95, 96, 95, 94, 93, 92, 91, 90, 89, 88, 
87, 86, 85, 84, 85, 86, 87, 86, 84, 85, 86, 87, 86, 87, 86, 85, 
84, 83, 84, 83, 82, 81, 80, 79, 78, 77, 76, 75), `ns1:Time` = structure(c(1525439315, 
1525439321, 1525439325, 1525439326, 1525439327, 1525439328, 1525439329, 
1525439330, 1525439332, 1525439333, 1525439335, 1525439337, 1525439339, 
1525439346, 1525439355, 1525439400, 1525439401, 1525439402, 1525439403, 
1525439405, 1525439406, 1525439407, 1525439409, 1525439410, 1525439413, 
1525439414, 1525439415, 1525439417, 1525439418, 1525439419, 1525439421, 
1525439425, 1525439429, 1525439430, 1525439432, 1525439433, 1525439434, 
1525439436, 1525439437, 1525439438, 1525439440, 1525439441, 1525439443, 
1525439444, 1525439445, 1525439447, 1525439448, 1525439451, 1525439452, 
1525439455, 1525439457, 1525439458, 1525439460, 1525439461, 1525439462, 
1525439463, 1525439464, 1525439466, 1525439467, 1525439469, 1525439471, 
1525439473, 1525439475, 1525439476, 1525439477, 1525439478, 1525439479, 
1525439480, 1525439481, 1525439483, 1525439484, 1525439486, 1525439488, 
1525439489, 1525439490, 1525439491, 1525439493, 1525439494, 1525439495, 
1525439496, 1525439497, 1525439499, 1525439500, 1525439502, 1525439504, 
1525439506, 1525439508, 1525439510, 1525439511, 1525439514, 1525439515, 
1525439516, 1525439517, 1525439519, 1525439526, 1525439531, 1525439536, 
1525439537, 1525439539, 1525439540, 1525439541, 1525439544, 1525439563, 
1525439577, 1525439587, 1525439588, 1525439589, 1525439590, 1525439591, 
1525439592, 1525439593, 1525439594, 1525439595, 1525439596, 1525439597, 
1525439598, 1525439599, 1525439600, 1525439601, 1525439602, 1525439604, 
1525439606, 1525439607, 1525439608, 1525439610, 1525439611, 1525439613, 
1525439614, 1525439616, 1525439618, 1525439620, 1525439621, 1525439623, 
1525439626, 1525439628, 1525439630, 1525439633, 1525439636, 1525439638, 
1525439640, 1525439641, 1525439644, 1525439647, 1525439651, 1525439656, 
1525439660, 1525439666, 1525439673, 1525439680, 1525439690, 1525439703, 
1525439704, 1525439705, 1525439717, 1525439728, 1525439732, 1525439733, 
1525439734, 1525439735, 1525439736, 1525439737, 1525439738, 1525439739, 
1525439740, 1525439741, 1525439742, 1525439743, 1525439749, 1525439751, 
1525439754, 1525439756, 1525439758, 1525439760, 1525439762, 1525439765, 
1525439766, 1525439767, 1525439768, 1525439769, 1525439770, 1525439771, 
1525439773, 1525439774, 1525439775, 1525439776, 1525439777, 1525439780, 
1525439782, 1525439784, 1525439785, 1525439786, 1525439788, 1525439791, 
1525439797, 1525439811, 1525439812, 1525439813, 1525439814, 1525439815, 
1525439816, 1525439819, 1525439820, 1525439821, 1525439822, 1525439823, 
1525439824, 1525439828, 1525439829, 1525439830, 1525439831, 1525439832, 
1525439833, 1525439834, 1525439835, 1525439836, 1525439837, 1525439838, 
1525439839, 1525439840, 1525439841, 1525439842, 1525439843, 1525439844, 
1525439846, 1525439847, 1525439849, 1525439850, 1525439852, 1525439853, 
1525439855, 1525439857, 1525439858, 1525439859, 1525439860, 1525439863, 
1525439864, 1525439865, 1525439866, 1525439870, 1525439872, 1525439880, 
1525439885, 1525439887, 1525439888, 1525439889, 1525439891, 1525439892, 
1525439894, 1525439895, 1525439896, 1525439898, 1525439899, 1525439901, 
1525439904, 1525439907, 1525439915, 1525439925, 1525439964, 1525439965, 
1525439966, 1525439967, 1525439970, 1525439975, 1525439987, 1525440021, 
1525440052, 1525440053, 1525440055, 1525440066, 1525440098, 1525440100, 
1525440101, 1525440102, 1525440104, 1525440105, 1525440106, 1525440108, 
1525440109, 1525440111, 1525440113, 1525440114, 1525440115, 1525440116, 
1525440117, 1525440118, 1525440120, 1525440122, 1525440124, 1525440125, 
1525440130, 1525440137, 1525440141, 1525440145, 1525440171, 1525440186, 
1525440189, 1525440194, 1525440202, 1525440203, 1525440204, 1525440205, 
1525440206, 1525440207, 1525440208, 1525440209, 1525440210, 1525440211, 
1525440213, 1525440214, 1525440216, 1525440218, 1525440220, 1525440222, 
1525440225, 1525440228, 1525440231, 1525440235, 1525440238, 1525440241, 
1525440246, 1525440251, 1525440256, 1525440267, 1525440268, 1525440269, 
1525440276, 1525440303, 1525440314, 1525440316, 1525440321, 1525440330, 
1525440331, 1525440332, 1525440334, 1525440351, 1525440364, 1525440408, 
1525440409, 1525440411, 1525440412, 1525440416, 1525440422, 1525440424, 
1525440427, 1525440430, 1525440436, 1525440454, 1525440457, 1525440458, 
1525440459, 1525440460, 1525440461, 1525440462, 1525440468, 1525440473, 
1525440479, 1525440503, 1525440508, 1525440509, 1525440513, 1525440530, 
1525440550, 1525440551, 1525440552, 1525440556, 1525440557, 1525440558, 
1525440563, 1525440572, 1525440576, 1525440579, 1525440607, 1525440609, 
1525440614, 1525440615, 1525440616, 1525440618, 1525440620, 1525440621, 
1525440623, 1525440627, 1525440628, 1525440629, 1525440630, 1525440635, 
1525440637, 1525440640, 1525440642, 1525440643, 1525440649, 1525440655, 
1525440668, 1525440676, 1525440692, 1525440714, 1525440725, 1525440729, 
1525440731, 1525440732, 1525440733, 1525440734, 1525440735, 1525440736, 
1525440737, 1525440744, 1525440746, 1525440747, 1525440748, 1525440749, 
1525440750, 1525440752, 1525440756, 1525440757, 1525440767, 1525440768, 
1525440769, 1525440770, 1525440771, 1525440772, 1525440773, 1525440775, 
1525440778, 1525440780, 1525440783, 1525440785, 1525440786, 1525440787, 
1525440789, 1525440790, 1525440792, 1525440795, 1525440799, 1525440803, 
1525440808, 1525440810, 1525440813, 1525440818, 1525440820, 1525440821, 
1525440822, 1525440826, 1525440831, 1525440838, 1525440839, 1525440848, 
1525440850, 1525440852, 1525440853, 1525440855, 1525440857, 1525440858, 
1525440862, 1525440867, 1525440871, 1525440907, 1525440908, 1525440909, 
1525440910, 1525440911, 1525440914, 1525440916, 1525440917, 1525440918, 
1525440919, 1525440920, 1525440938, 1525440952, 1525440962, 1525440970, 
1525440975, 1525441002, 1525441014, 1525441015, 1525441017, 1525441019, 
1525441020, 1525441021, 1525441024, 1525441028, 1525441033, 1525441034, 
1525441036, 1525441048, 1525441054, 1525441056, 1525441057, 1525441078, 
1525441079, 1525441081, 1525441083, 1525441085, 1525441087, 1525441089, 
1525441091, 1525441093, 1525441096, 1525441098, 1525441100, 1525441103, 
1525441106), tzone = "GMT", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))), row.names = c(NA, 
-500L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```
dput(A02_pre_hr)
structure(list(results_id = c(17817, 17817, 17817, 17817, 17817, 
17817, 17817, 17817, 17817, 17817, 17817, 17817, 17817, 17817, 
17817, 17817, 17817, 17817, 17817, 17817, 17817, 17817, 17817, 
17817, 17817, 17817, 17817, 17817, 17817, 17817, 17817, 17817, 
17817, 17817, 17817, 17817, 17817, 17817, 17817, 17817, 17817, 
17817, 17817, 17817, 17817), start = structure(c(1525439377, 
1525439400, 1525439460, 1525439520, 1525439580, 1525439640, 1525439700, 
1525439760, 1525439781, 1525439783, 1525439820, 1525439880, 1525439940, 
1525439954, 1525439957, 1525440000, 1525440051, 1525440053, 1525440058, 
1525440060, 1525440120, 1525440180, 1525440240, 1525440300, 1525440360, 
1525440420, 1525440480, 1525440540, 1525440600, 1525440660, 1525440720, 
1525440780, 1525440840, 1525440900, 1525440960, 1525441020, 1525441080, 
1525441140, 1525441200, 1525441260, 1525441320, 1525441380, 1525441440, 
1525441500, 1525441560), tzone = "GMT", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), duration = c(22.37, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 21.04, 
2.65, 36.32, 60, 60, 14.58, 3.07, 42.35, 51.38, 2.46, 4.78, 1.38, 
60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 
60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60), class = c("standing", 
"standing", "standing", "standing", "standing", "standing", "standing", 
"standing", "walking", "standing", "standing", "standing", "standing", 
"sitting", "standing", "standing", "walking", "standing", "lying", 
"lying", "lying", "lying", "lying", "lying", "lying", "lying", 
"lying", "lying", "lying", "lying", "lying", "lying", "lying", 
"lying", "lying", "lying", "lying", "lying", "lying", "lying", 
"lying", "lying", "lying", "lying", "lying"), steps = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), mi = c(2, 12, 1, 11, 2, 102, 329, 285, 351, 193, 190, 225, 
148, 361, 180, 226, 230, 379, 349, 212, 30, 125, 225, 36, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10, 40, 8, 8, 9, 8, 9, 9, 10, 9, 7, 2
), aee = c(16, 21, 15, 20, 16, 64, 173, 151, 313, 107, 106, 123, 
86, 129, 101, 123, 246, 197, 448, 272, 38, 160, 289, 46, 1, 1, 
1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 12, 51, 10, 10, 11, 10, 11, 11, 12, 11, 
9, 2), tee = c(91, 96, 90, 96, 91, 144, 265, 242, 421, 192, 191, 
210, 169, 216, 186, 210, 346, 292, 571, 375, 116, 251, 394, 124, 
74, 74, 74, 76, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 87, 130, 84, 84, 86, 84, 
86, 86, 87, 86, 83, 76), met = c(1.145, 1.208, 1.139, 1.201, 
1.145, 1.767, 3.18, 2.906, 6.847, 2.334, 2.315, 2.533, 2.054, 
2.424, 2.253, 2.539, 5.12, 3.491, 7.275, 4.802, 1.516, 3.231, 
5.036, 1.624, 0.992, 0.992, 0.992, 1.01, 0.992, 0.992, 0.992, 
0.992, 0.992, 1.155, 1.697, 1.119, 1.119, 1.137, 1.119, 1.137, 
1.137, 1.155, 1.137, 1.101, 1.01), counts = c(14, 138, 0, 256, 
0, 2059, 7922, 2162, 394, 2952, 2886, 3888, 782, 62, 2163, 3041, 
128, 560, 169, 3506, 432, 2024, 3825, 844, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 392, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), averageHeartRate = c(104, 
100.236842105263, 88.6904761904762, 64.9, 81.1944444444444, 70, 
80.4347826086957, 90.1333333333333, 97, 108.285714285714, 103.775, 
93.2941176470588, NA, NA, 97.7142857142857, 100, 98.5, 97.5, 
NA, 89.5, 83, 105.833333333333, 99.5, 94.5555555555556, 91.8333333333333, 
100.4, 104.8, 104.7, 97, 99, 87.4642857142857, 76.4090909090909, 
87.5, 91.3076923076923, 88, 85.6923076923077, 82.0714285714286, 
91.2, 86.6428571428571, 90.6363636363636, 105.142857142857, 95.5, 
94.1, 102.5, 93.8333333333333)), row.names = c(NA, -45L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: I suspect this could be done *without using loops at all*.  (R is vectorised by default, after all.)  But to be sure it would be helpful to have (a) access to your input data and (b) a clear statement of the calculation you are trying to perform.  Welcome to SO, by the way!

Comment: I expect this could be improved to take less than 1 minute. But without an example of input data that's difficult to tell.

Comment: I guess you could improve performance already a lot by removing the `print(i)` line.

Comment: Thanks for the reply's and the tips. I added the data and the rest of the script, is this enough to help improve the script?

Comment: at first, this syntax doesn't seem to be able to read. I suggest `dplyr` (you probably don't need any loop at all)

Comment: The new information is a good start.  Thank you.  Now please explain what you are trying to do.  In other words, what's the desired transformation of your input data?  Also,  given your test data, what is the expected output?  By the way, using `dput()` is far more convenient than `head()` for providing your test data: the output is in a format that we can copy-and-paste directly in the console.

Comment: Hi Limey, thanks for your feedback and your quick response. 

I'm trying to get an average heart rate out of every activity. The heart rate has been measured with a sports watch and the activities (sitting, lying, walking etc) have been measured with an accelerometer (which in turn estimates what kind of activity was being done) . I'll edit my text with the data from the dput function!

Comment: Edit: the data added is a small snippet from the actual data

Comment: Transform your data frame/tibble in a list of vectors where each list will represent a column. It'll improve significantly your speed.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to get an average heart rate out of every activity. The
> heart rate has been measured with a sports watch and the activities
> (sitting, lying, walking etc) have been measured with an accelerometer
> (which in turn estimates what kind of activity was being done).

You could use a data.table non-qui join with `by = .EACHI`. That should be quite fast.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(A02_pre_hr)
setDT(A02_pre)

A02_pre_hr[, start := as.POSIXct(start)]
A02_pre_hr[, end := start + duration]
A02_pre[, time := as.POSIXct(`ns1:Time`)]

A02_pre_hr[, averageHeartRate1 := A02_pre[A02_pre_hr, mean(`ns1:Value4`, na.rm = TRUE), 
                                          on = c("time >= start", "time <= end"), by = .EACHI]$V1]

#   results_id               start duration    class steps  mi aee tee   met counts averageHeartRate                 end averageHeartRate1
# 1:      17817 2018-05-04 13:09:37    22.37 standing     0   2  16  91 1.145     14        104.00000 2018-05-04 13:09:59               NaN
# 2:      17817 2018-05-04 13:10:00    60.00 standing     0  12  21  96 1.208    138        100.23684 2018-05-04 13:11:00         100.23684
# 3:      17817 2018-05-04 13:11:00    60.00 standing     0   1  15  90 1.139      0         88.69048 2018-05-04 13:12:00          88.69048
# 4:      17817 2018-05-04 13:12:00    60.00 standing     0  11  20  96 1.201    256         64.90000 2018-05-04 13:13:00          64.90000
# 5:      17817 2018-05-04 13:13:00    60.00 standing     0   2  16  91 1.145      0         81.19444 2018-05-04 13:14:00          81.19444
# 6:      17817 2018-05-04 13:14:00    60.00 standing     0 102  64 144 1.767   2059         70.00000 2018-05-04 13:15:00          70.00000
# 7:      17817 2018-05-04 13:15:00    60.00 standing     0 329 173 265 3.180   7922         80.43478 2018-05-04 13:16:00          80.43478
# ....
```

The first value doesn't match because of the subseconds in the duration.

Comment: Thank you so much!